# is there a way to retrieve data from firebase in a given set of categories using android spinners?

Tags: android, firebase

This is my Database structure[image] This is my spinner containing a set of categories

```
    String[] items = new String[]{"Office and School supplies","Furniture","Automobiles and Motorycles","Electronics","Arts and Decoration","Entertainment","Other Accessories"};
    Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Please your database structure and indicate what categories you want to get. In your code, there is only a String array.

Comment: I want to get the data in my String array as categories.

Comment: @AlexMamo And my database structure is as follows:                                                                                                                   Member-->imageurl: "https:....."                                                                                                     
                  name:"dress"

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I just did

Comment: I still don't understand. There are no categories in your database. What do you want to get from the database?